# Cannot telnet to Postgresql Forwarded Port

Tags: remote, debugging, port-forwarding, postgresql

I'm trying to portforward a PostgreSQL port using my DLINK ADSL Router.
I have the following IP addresses.

```
Public Internet IP   197.321.321.32 
PostgreSQL           192.123.123.12:5432    (Port To Forward CentOS 7)
```

I've configured PostgreSQL to allow remote connections as well as disabled firewalld and selinux for testing purposes.

postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

pg_hba.conf

```
# LAN connections
host    dbname    usname    192.123.123.0/24    md5
# Internet connections
host    dbname    usname    197.321.321.0/24    md5
```

All the computers on the LAN can connect to PostgreSQL fine.

Then I did the port forwarding.

```
Server Name    External Port    Protocol    Internal Port   Server IP Address   Use Interface   Lan Loopback    Schedule Rule
pbpgsql        5432 to 5432     TCP         5432 to 5432    192.123.123.12      ppp0.1          Disabled        Always
```

I tried to telnet to test the port

```
telnet 197.321.321.321.32 5432
```

Which gives me the response

```
telnet: connect to address 197.321.321.32: Connection refused
```

Why is this? I can't connect to the PostgreSQL port from outside the LAN but inside the LAN it works fine

Comment: maybe there is a problem with copy-paste but ip 197.321.321.32 is incorrect. you cant have an octet > 254

Comment: The IP is just a bogus one to protect the integrity of the server

Comment: @Trent, is there a managed firewall that you are unaware of?

Comment: @Daniel after some investigation it seemed that having a database port forwarded on the network was a bad idea. Instead I forwarded the web server instead and interfaced with the database using APIs which seems like the safer way to do things

Comment: @Trent, you should go ahead and post that as your answer then, so that others may benefit.

Comment: it isnt really a solution though, more of a work around. i dont know how to close the question